# Automate to pick a certain date from a calendar using robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

i want to automate to choose a date from a calendar.
Currently am entering date in date fields its working for departure date but not for return date.
But there is not any error in logs.
Please let me know if there is any way to do it.

```
    [Arguments]   ${justfly policy number}   ${depart date}    ${returnDate}
    Enter Valid policy number    ${justfly policy number}
    Enter valid depart date      ${depart date}
    Enter valid return date      ${returnDate}


Enter valid depart date
   [Arguments]   ${depart date}
   Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  60s   1s   Input Text    ${date of departure}       ${depart date}


Enter valid return date
    [Arguments]     ${returnDate}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  60s   1s   Input Text    ${travel return date}            ${returnDate}
```

Comment: You need to add the code of keyword `Enter valid return date`

Comment: @Würgspaß added , NOTE : its working for depart date but not for return date.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the web element denoted by `${travel return date}` is not located, loaded, inactive, hidden, ... or does not accept text for some reason. Lots of possibilites though in most cases you should get an appropriate error message. Have a close look at both web elements. The one which is working and the other and find out what is the difference. Without HTML/JS code it is next to impossible to guess. If it is a date picker with AngularJS then you might end up with writing JS code because Selenium sometimes cannot handle those elements. Note, that this is probably a Selenium issue

Comment: "is not working" is a rather vague description. Can you describe a bit more what you see happening?

Comment: @ A. Kootstra  not working i meant , only partial date is getting entered but in result logs no errors, it says complete date has been and test case is getting passed in result logs, but not proceeding in UI.